# How to handle the concurrent write to a single field in a single document in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am wondering how to handle the concurrent write in Firestore.

**The scenario:**

A HTML form is submitted from the frontend directly. Security rules will be applied. I have setup the callback with Cloud Functions to do the post-operation. I have also handled the unique time of the callback. (So that each callback is only called once per each request, refer to this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-count-documents-in-firestore-a0527f792d04), point 2.4)

For each callback, I would like to summerise the "amount" field which is an integer type provided by the user. The total amount will be stored in a separated document, e.g. summaryCollection/summaryDoc/totalAmount

If there are concurrently 10 users who submit the form at the same time, e.g.
user 1: amount: 10
user 2: amount: 20
user 3: amount: 30
.
.
.
user 10: amount: 100

Will the value of totalAmount exactly be (10 + 20 + ... + 100) = 550??

Do I need to add the Firestore transaction code even in the callback onCreate? Will there be 2 or more callbacks get called at the same time? Because I need to read to get the latest value of totalAmount and make the sum from the new amount.

Alternatively, if I don't use the callback method and create a Cloud Function to handle a POST request instead, how to handle the concurrent write to the totalAmount? Can [Firestore Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) solve the problem?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the instructions of the first article you [pointed out](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-count-documents-in-firestore-a0527f792d04#:%7E:text=here%20is%20a%20simpler%20version.) you shouldn't need any transaction code in there.

Firestore Transaction is better suited for editing and or consulting more than one document. If your call will be only to your document with only the total amount is better to use something like the [onSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) function.